# Interpreting a covariance between two values of a dummy variable large relative to the variances of these dummy variables.

Tags: anova

Previously, answers have been provided for questions about the standard errors and the covariance of beta coefficients for a dummy variable (linear) regression model with an intercept.  In a single dummy variable regression with an intercept on observational data, how does one interpret the covariance between the two values of the dummy variable when the estimated value of this covariance is large relative to each of the estimated variances for these two values?  Can one compare/plot correlations based on this covariance for different models when this covariance is smaller or larger? Because of this covariance, the variance of the estimate of the difference between these two values of the dummy variables may often be much smaller or larger than the variances of the estimates of these two values themselves.  Thus, the t-test of differences between the estimates of the two values of the dummy variables in regression output may be misleading because it does not account for the covariance between these estimates.

Comment: I lost you at the phrase "covariance between the two values of the dummy variable."  I cannot make sense of it because by definition those values are *mutually exclusive*; they cannot have a covariance.  Could you clarify what you are referring to?

Comment: The situation is more complicated than I described.  The two means are the so-called "least-square" means of a dependent variable in a linear regression for the two values of the dummy variable adjusted for the values of other independent variables in the regression.  The statistical program outputting these adjusted means outputs a variance for each mean as well as a covariance between these two means (even though these means are "mutually exclusive").  Comparing the difference between these two adjusted means requires accounting for each of their variances as well as this covariance.